How to create a for loop for a LARGE array
I want to create a flexible signal shape that can be viewed using an oscilloscope by making a program. I am using an array to form the signal, such as {2048, 4026, 2048, 0}, where 2048 represents the flat line I want to adjust, 4026 represents the peak, and 0 represents the valley. I want to adjust the value of 2048 flexibly; for example, if I input x=3, it should output {2048, 4026, 2048, 2048, 2048, 0}. However, I am confused about how to use the for loop or if statements because I want to place the value in the middle. I need help with my code; please provide suggestions or possibly an example code.
the result i want
That is the description of what I want to create, and here is my code.
The code like 2048 is the part that I want to make flexible.
#define NS 4
uint32_t Wave_LUT[NS] = {
2048,4026, 2048,0
};
HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, Wave_LUT, 4, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim4);

Please help me, I really can’t analogize this anymore.

hallo can anyone help me, urgent!!

For me, a few details are unclear. What have you tried so far to fill the array and what exactly is stopping you? A for loop looks like being absolute beginner's topic, therefore what is the issue there? Are the size of the array and the possible range for x known in advance? Also, what if statements are you talking about? You did not mention any conditional behaviour.

You need to think about what you actually want to do here. #define NS 2048 would give you a much bigger array (although 16 might be enough to learn how to use a for loop). I presume your DAC is 0..4096 (aka 12 bits) ? You should try write a routine to assign the waveform that you want and add it to the question. Hint: the routine should accept x the delay you want between positive and negative pulses.

I'm confused about how to create a loop that generates an output like the image I attached, nothing more than that. Yes, I'm a beginner, which is why I'm confused @Gerhardh

Can you provide me with a simple example? I'm still confused. In short, I just want the integer 2048 to be adjustable through an for loop, But 2048 must remain constant in the middle because it's actually the midpoint between 4026 and 0. @MartinBrown

An array with 4 elements (uint32_t Wave_LUT[4] = {2048, 4026, 2048, 0};) cannot ever hold 6 values.

That was my mistake earlier; let's assume I can store 1000 values in the array. I'm just confused about how to program it. The logic is, if I initially had {2048, 4026, 2048, 0}, I want to modify it to {2048, 4026, x, 0}. When I set x = 10, the value 2048 should appear 10 times. I want to have different values for x, so the result would be something like {2048, 4026, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 0}. @pmg can you give me another example because I'm really a beginner and I really need this

You need to use dynamic memory (malloc() and friends). I suggest you write a function which creates a brand new array and leaves the original array alone.

BTW: The middle between 0 and 4026 is not 2048 but 2013. Do you actually mean 4095 as maximum value for DAC?

You ask how to pre-compute a sampled waveform which your program then sends to the hardware. We don't know anything about the hardware platform you are using, and we don't know much about the problem that you are trying to solve, but for some platforms and for some problems, it can make more sense to compute the samples "on-the-fly." That is, instead of storing them in memory, you send them directly to the hardware, in real-time, as they are needed. OTOH, on some other platforms, it simply is not possible to do it that way. Anyway, not an "answer," just something for you to think about.

Any update here?

this is all i want and itis can work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78943744/how-to-create-a-for-loop-program-that-can-change-middle-values-flexibly/78952255#78952255

You did not show how NS and x are related. In this example I will assume that NS is always large enough to hold the resulting array.
From your examples I get a few fixed values.
Your array layout is always like this:

First value is 2048
Second value is 4026
x values are 2048
Last value is 0

That means, you have in total x+3 elements in your array and all but 2 have the same value.
Let's fill the values in:
#include <stdint.h> // for uint32_t etc.
#include <stdio.h>  // for perror
#include <stdlib.h> // for exit

#define NS 1000
uint32_t Wave_LUT[NS];

void Init_DAC_Array(size_t x)
{
  if (x+3 > NS)
  {
    perror("x exceeds array size!");
    exit(1);
  }

  // For simplicity we just fill all the array up with 2048u.
  for (size_t i = 0u; i < x+3u; i++)
  {
    Wave_LUT[i] = 2048u;
  }
  Wave_LUT[1] = 4026u;
  Wave_LUT[x+2u] = 0u;
}

If you really want to save every nanosecond you could modify the filling part like this:
  Wave_LUT[0] = 2048u;
  Wave_LUT[1] = 4026u;
  for (size_t i = 2u; i < x+2u; i++)
  {
    Wave_LUT[i] = 2048u;
  }
  Wave_LUT[x+2u] = 0u;


Thank you for your response, and I have tried it, but why is the result of the array 0? I have reduced the range to 10, but the result of all wave_LUT values is 0. I will send my program via a link, please help me with it. @Gerhardh https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15iOijzdSCBiSanSQd-uQ1jHjVPdu-xGV?usp=sharing

What is "the result of the array"?

i give the result from program and result real that i want  where x determines the distance between peaks and valleys, but with the array size as specified in the program I provided., thank u please help me.

Again, what is "result"? Did you look at the array in a debugger? What is the content of the array after you call that function? You do call that function, do  you?

Please add your source to the question. I can't access your link from this PC. Remove all unrelated parts. See MCVE for details. All that HAL DAC or timer related stuff is not required to fill your array. And, honestly: If you have problems filling an array with such a simple pattern, I doubt that you are ready for dealing with such low level programming involving timers, DAC and DMA.

I have now checked your link (and ask you again to provide everything important here!). You did not call that function at all. You cannot expect a function to do something if you don't call it.

I'm afraid your specification is unclear but I'll offer one potential solution using run length encoding to represent the waveform in a more compact form. It could be more refined but it does the bare bones. The value which is presently 5 is your x and could be varied provided that you keep total length the same.
It is about as simple as I can make it and still have sufficient flexibility to cope with your actual requirements (which seems to be a positive pulse off a baseline of 2048 followed by a negative pulse x samples later). Unclear to me if the pulse shape needs to have rounded tops or not.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NLUT 16   // length of wave LUT

void RLE_to_WaveLUT(uint32_t* RLE, uint32_t rlen, uint32_t* Wave, uint32_t n)
{
   uint32_t i, j, idx = 0, sum = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < rlen; i += 2)
      sum += RLE[i];
   if (sum != NLUT)
   {
      printf("Mismatch REL entries total %u but Wave table length is %u", sum, n);
      exit(-1);
   }
   for (i = 0; i < rlen; i += 2)
      for (j = 0; j<RLE[i]; j++)
         Wave[idx++] = RLE[i + 1];
}

// RLE table consists of a "repeat count, DACvalue" pair to define the Wave array.
uint32_t RLE[] = { 1, 2048, 1, 4095, 5, 2048, 1, 0, 8, 2048 };  

int main()
{
   uint32_t Wave_LUT[NLUT];
   uint32_t RLELEN = sizeof RLE / (sizeof uint32_t);
   RLE_to_WaveLUT(RLE, RLELEN, Wave_LUT, NLUT);
   printf("RLE encoded values:\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < RLELEN; i+=2) printf(" %u x '%u' ", RLE[i], RLE[i+1]);
   printf("\n\nWave table:\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < NLUT; i++) printf(" %u", Wave_LUT[i]);
   printf("\n");
}

And the output is a summary of the RLE input "Count x DACvalue" followed by the actual wavetable that it generates when decoded. This should have enough flexibility to let you do any waveform.
RLE encoded values:
 1 x '2048'  1 x '4095'  5 x '2048'  1 x '0'  8 x '2048'

Wave table:
 2048 4095 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 0 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048 2048

BTW A simple ramp is a better choice for initially testing that you have got the DMA hardware working right.

You're right, I'm too much of a beginner to understand the meaning of all those functions. Thank you for your help and response. I've now found that it's actually very simple, but I'm still stuck with some problems
